# Selenium IDE record doesn't work

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

The title says it all.  The "Record" feature in the Selenium IDE doesn't do anything.  I'm using FF 28 & IDE 2.5.

What's up?

Comment: I think Firefox just released a new version.  You may need to wait for a new version of the IDE, or downgrade to FF 27.

Comment: Is it working for you with FF 27?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would uninstall Selenium IDE and use [Selenium Builder](https://seleniumbuilder.github.io/se-builder/) instead.  Selenium Builder was created by SauceLabs and given to the Selenium project in order to soon replace the IDE plugin.  Also, [I developed a framework](https://github.com/djangofan/simple-selenium-builder-framework) to run Builder scripts.

Comment: ok, that sounded like a good idea.  I uninstalled Selenium IDE & installed Selenium Builder, but there isn't any button to start it from FF.

Comment: The button is in the Tools-->Web Developer Tools menu.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same version of both selenium and FF.

i think you accidentally change the format.

for restoration please go to IDE >> option >> Format >> HTML.